# WPF toolkit charting question

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I am trying to make a simple line graph using WPF toolkit and I am running into problems that I can't seem to resolve.

The relevant part of my XAML code is:

```
    <DockPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
        <charting:Chart Name="orignialDataGraph" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="474" Title="Original Signal">
            <charting:Chart.Series>
                <charting:LineSeries Title="Original"
                    DependentValueBinding="{Binding SamplePeriod}" 
                    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding TraceValue}">

                </charting:LineSeries>
            </charting:Chart.Series>
        </charting:Chart>
    </DockPanel>
```

And the code behind:

```
    private void LoadSignals_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ofd.InitialDirectory = ofd.FileName;
            try
            {
                string fileName = ofd.FileName;
                StudyFile sf = new StudyFile(fileName);
                studyDataList = sf.GetStudyData();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        LineSeries ls = (LineSeries)orignialDataGraph.Series[0];
        ls.ItemsSource = studyDataList;
    }
```

I get the following error:

A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll

I've googled to see if I can find something relevant but the ones I could find were only relevant to silverlight (which I don't know much of except for its name). I've checked and confirmed that "studyDataList" list is populated. Can anyone give a helping hand? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The name of the binding variable in XAML was incorrect.